# How should I reopen a failed WCF channel?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm using a client-side proxy object to access a WCF channel. To access any of the service methods, the call is wrapped in a try-catch to ensure well defined behavior.

However, once the channel is nonfunctional for any reason, I would like to reopen it. What is the proper way to do that? I see two questions:

**1. When to check**

- right before the try/catch in the access methods
- via the Faulted, Aborted, etc events of the channel

**2. How to perform the reopen**

This troubled me quite a bit. If i understand the situation correctly, I have to handle every possible state separately. Also, I possibly have to avoid threading issues such as opening the channel twice if two method calls were received at the same time (only applies to option A of the previous point).

I recall there being a lot of things to consider when reopening a channel. It is required to differentiate between Faulted and Closed (and Closing), order of operations does matter, and certain operations invalidate the object (?).

And as if that were not enough trouble, the MSDN apparently provides wrong example code (missing cases, sloppily dealing with edge conditions etc.)  so I can't rely on that at all.

Answer (score 3):

Channel cannot be reopened. The only valid state shift once the channel is in `Faulted` state is calling `Abort`. Once you abort the current channel / proxy you can start the new one and establish new connection to the server.

Comment: not sure if you read his question all the way through.  Only one of the cases he wants to consider is Faulted.  How would you handle the other cases?

Comment: @Lucas: Any other case is the same - channel cannot be reopened. Once the channel is Faulted, Closed or Closing it is simply gone.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is what I currently use:

```
class FooProxy : IFoo
{
    private readonly object _Sync = new object ();
    private IFoo Channel;

    public FooProxy ()
    {
    }

    private void CreateChannel ()
    {
        lock (_Sync) {
            if (Channel != null) {
                if (((ICommunicationObject) Channel).State == CommunicationState.Opened) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Attempt to create new connection
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IFoo> (...);
            var channel = factory.CreateChannel ();

            ((ICommunicationObject) channel).Faulted += (s, e) => ((ICommunicationObject) Channel).Abort ();

            try {
                ((ICommunicationObject) channel).Open ();
            }
            catch (EndpointNotFoundException) {
                // dont worry
                return;
            }

            Channel = channel;
        }
    }

    public string DoStuff ()
    {
        // try to create a channel in case it's not there
        CreateChannel ();

        try {
            return Channel.DoStuff ();
        }
        // something goes wrong -> ensure well defined behavior
        catch (CommunicationException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```